# Mappings for an integral scheme with generic point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be an integral scheme with generic point $\eta$.

Show that for any $x \in X$, there is a canonical ring homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$.

For any open subset $U \subset X$ and any point $x \in U$, show that the canonical homomorphisms $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ are injective.

Identifying $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ with subrings of $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ show that $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)=\bigcap_{x \in U} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$

My idea for the third question was to reduce this to the case where $U$ is affine by means of an inverse limit argument. Then I can just work with primes in some domain $R$.

The injectivity argument for $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ seems clear from taking $U=\textrm{Spec} R$ for $R$ a domain to be some open affine neighborhood of $x$.

I'm a little unsure of how to approach the ring homomorphism argument and the other injectivity argument...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is probably easiest of you think of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ as being the collection of pairs $(U,t)$, where $x\in U$ and $t\in\mathcal{O}_X (U)$, with the equivalence relation $(U,t) \sim (U',t')$ if $t|_{U\cap U'} = t'_{U\cap U'}$.

1) If an element of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ has a representative $t\in \mathcal{O}_X (U)$ on some $x\in U\subset X$ with $U$ nonempty, then $\eta\in U$, giving an obvious map $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$.  The only question is whether this map is well-defined.  But it is not so hard to show that the equivalence relation on $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ is stronger than the one on $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

2) For the first one, non-injectivity would mean that there is some smaller open on which $t$ vanishes.  Since $t$ must fail to vanish on some affine open, and all nonempty open subsets intersect, we can work locally as you say.

The second is similar; we can work locally.

Both could also be done this way: The set of points on which some $t\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ vanishes is the complement of the closed subscheme defined by the annihilator.  But all annihilators are trivial on an integral scheme.

3) One direction is clear.  To show that $\bigcap_{x\in U} \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \subset \mathcal{O}_X(U)$,consider both as subsets of $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$.  The left side is exactly the rational functions $f$ such that, for each $x\in U$, there is some open set $U_x$ containing $x$ on which $f_x$ is defined and restricts to $f\in\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$.  We can check that the collection $\{f_x\}$ satisfies the sheaf condition on the cover $\{U_x\}$, and glue.

Comment: For 1), actually every relation $x \in \overline{\{y\}}$ in a ringed space induces a homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,y}$. In the case of schemes it is a localization.

Comment: This is a good thing to point out.  It seems like this is true for any kind of sheaf.  I assume that you were just making a general comment, but I didn't make any assumptions specific schemes in 1) did I?